# How do you make a class that changes position of objects based on it's order in a list?

Tags: python, pygame

Basically, I am writing an 'Enemy' class that takes in an image from a list of images and a position number (o), and assigns it to its position on the screen. Variable o is set to -1 initially.

How I want this to work is if I create instances of the Enemy class up to 3, then it assigns the first instance to the first image in the image list, and first position in the position list so first one would have position (1000,0).

The purpose is so that I can create enemies that spawn on the outer edges of my screen, but I want to control how many I spawn.

If there is an easier way to code this, please tell me.

```
    o = -1
    class Enemy(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, enemyImageList,o):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(enemyImageList[o]),(40,40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if o == 0:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 1:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 100
        elif o == 2:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 200
        elif o == 3:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 300
        elif o == 4:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 400            
        elif o == 5:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 500            
        elif o == 6:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 600            
        elif o == 7:
            self.rect[0] = 1000
            self.rect[1] = 700
        elif o == 8:
            self.rect[0] = 900
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 9:
            self.rect[0] = 800
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 10:
            self.rect[0] = 700
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 11:
            self.rect[0] = 600
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 12:
            self.rect[0] = 500
            self.rect[1] = 0            
        elif o == 13:
            self.rect[0] = 400
            self.rect[1] = 0            
        elif o == 14:
            self.rect[0] = 300
            self.rect[1] = 0            
        elif o == 15:
            self.rect[0] = 200
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 16:
            self.rect[0] = 100
            self.rect[1] = 0
        elif o == 17:
            self.rect[0] = 0
            self.rect[1] = 0

        # Set image to be a file on the system.
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        # Set background to transparent.
    def update(self):
        if self.rect != player.rect:
            if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
                self.rect.x += 1
            if self.rect.x > player.rect.x:
                self.rect.x -= 1
            if self.rect.y < player.rect.y:
                self.rect.y += 1
            if self.rect.y > player.rect.y:
                self.rect.y -= 1

    def draw(screen, self):
        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)


enemySprite = sprite.Group()

enemy1 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy1)
enemySprite.add(enemy1)
o+=1
enemy2 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy2)
enemySprite.add(enemy2)
o+=1
enemy3 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy3)
enemySprite.add(enemy3)
o+=1
enemy4 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy4)
o+=1
enemy5 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy5)
o+=1
enemy6 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy6)
o+=1
enemy7 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy7)
o+=1
enemy8 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy8)
o+=1
enemy9 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy9)
o+=1
enemy10 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy10)
o+=1
enemy11= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy11)
o+=1
enemy12= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy12)
o+=1
enemy13= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy13)
o+=1
enemy14= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy14)
o+=1
enemy15= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy15)
o+=1
enemy16= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy16)
o+=1
enemy17= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy17)
o+=1
enemy18= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy18)
o+=1
enemy19= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy19)
o+=1
enemy20= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy20)
o+=1
enemy21= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy21)
o+=1
enemy22= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy22)
o+=1
enemy23= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy23)
o+=1
enemy24= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy24)
o+=1
enemy25= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy25)
o+=1
enemy26= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy26)
o+=1
enemy27= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy27)
o+=1
enemy28= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy28)
o+=1
enemy29 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy29)
o+=1
enemy30 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy30)
o+=1
```

Comment: Use the `dict` Luke.  `data = {0: (1000, 0), ...` and then `self.rect = data[o]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first long set of lines:

```
    if o == 0:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 1:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 100
    elif o == 2:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 200
    elif o == 3:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 300
    elif o == 4:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 400            
    elif o == 5:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 500            
    elif o == 6:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 600            
    elif o == 7:
        self.rect[0] = 1000
        self.rect[1] = 700
    elif o == 8:
        self.rect[0] = 900
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 9:
        self.rect[0] = 800
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 10:
        self.rect[0] = 700
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 11:
        self.rect[0] = 600
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 12:
        self.rect[0] = 500
        self.rect[1] = 0            
    elif o == 13:
        self.rect[0] = 400
        self.rect[1] = 0            
    elif o == 14:
        self.rect[0] = 300
        self.rect[1] = 0            
    elif o == 15:
        self.rect[0] = 200
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 16:
        self.rect[0] = 100
        self.rect[1] = 0
    elif o == 17:
        self.rect[0] = 0
        self.rect[1] = 0
```

Can be reduced to something like:

```
    RECTS = [
        [1000,   0],    # 0
        [1000, 100],    # 1
        [1000, 200],    # 2
        [1000, 300],    # 3
        [1000, 400],    # 4
        [1000, 500],    # 5
        [1000, 600],    # 6
        [1000, 700],
        [ 900,   0],
        [ 800,   0],
        [ 900,   0],
        [ 600,   0],
        [ 500,   0],
        [ 400,   0],
        [ 300,   0],
        [ 200,   0],
        [ 100,   0],    # 16
        [   0,   0],    # 17
    ]

    self.rect[0] = RECTS[o][0]
    self.rect[1] = RECTS[o][1]
```

Or even fewer lines (note: this only mimics what you've written in your if/elif ladder):

```
if o < 8:
    self.rect[0] = 1000
    self.rect[1] = 100 * i
else:
    self.rect[0] = 1000 - 100 * (i - 7)
    self.rect[1] = 0
```

And this set of lines:

```
enemySprite = sprite.Group()

enemy1 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy1)
enemySprite.add(enemy1)
o+=1
enemy2 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy2)
enemySprite.add(enemy2)
o+=1
enemy3 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy3)
enemySprite.add(enemy3)
o+=1
enemy4 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy4)
o+=1
enemy5 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy5)
o+=1
enemy6 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy6)
o+=1
enemy7 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy7)
o+=1
enemy8 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy8)
o+=1
enemy9 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy9)
o+=1
enemy10 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy10)
o+=1
enemy11= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy11)
o+=1
enemy12= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy12)
o+=1
enemy13= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy13)
o+=1
enemy14= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy14)
o+=1
enemy15= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy15)
o+=1
enemy16= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy16)
o+=1
enemy17= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy17)
o+=1
enemy18= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy18)
o+=1
enemy19= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy19)
o+=1
enemy20= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy20)
o+=1
enemy21= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy21)
o+=1
enemy22= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy22)
o+=1
enemy23= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy23)
o+=1
enemy24= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy24)
o+=1
enemy25= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy25)
o+=1
enemy26= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy26)
o+=1
enemy27= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy27)
o+=1
enemy28= Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy28)
o+=1
enemy29 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy29)
o+=1
enemy30 = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
enemyList.append(enemy30)
o+=1
```

Can be reduced to:

```
for o in range(30):
    enemy = Enemy(enemyImageList, o)
    enemyList.append(enemy)
    enemySprite.add(enemy)
```

But you'll soon see that, since you're creating 30 enemies but your `RECTS` list only has 18 elements, you'll get an `IndexError`.  And if you use the second `if o < 8:...` approach, you'll start getting negative values in `self.rect[0]`, so you'll want to figure out how to best handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a dictionary of tuples value for the "o" value.

```
locationDict = {0: (1000, 0), 1: (1000: 100), ....}
location = locationDict(o)
self.rect[0] = location[0]
self.rect[1] = location[1]
```

If I were you, I would have a generic Enemy class, and Enemies class to store all active enemies. (Also, I am not sure what "o" variable stand for, I am assuming it is location.)

```
class Enemy(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, o=-1):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(enemyImageList[o]),(40,40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        locationDict = {0: (1000, 0), 1: (1000: 100), ....}
        location = sizeDict(o)
        self.rect[0] = location[0]
        self.rect[1] = location[1]

    def updateO(o):
        self.o = o
        location = self.locationDict[0]
        self.rect[0] = location[0]
        self.rect[1] = location[1]

class Enemies():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.enemyList = []

    def addEnemy(enemy):
        self.enemyList.append(enemy)

    def GetDefualtEnemies():
        for i in range(30):
            self.addEnemy(Enemy(i))
```

The benefits of using a dictionary oppose to a 2 dimension list would be you have the key value represent certain types of enemies. For example, locationDict = {"Ninjas": (100, 0)...}, As for using a class based Enemies class, the code is easier to read and understand.